# What is wrong with my prime number list module?

Tags: python, numbers

i made a prime number checker in primenumber.py

```
def isPrimeNumber(n):
    if n > 1:
       for i in range(2,n):
           if (n % i) == 0:
               return False
       else:
           return True
    else:
       return False

    return True
```

and i made a series of prime number less than (n)

```
from primenumber import isPrimeNumber
def factorialofprimes(n):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if isPrimeNumber(i) == False:
            break
        elif isPrimeNumber(i):
            primes.append(i)
    return primes

print(factorialofprimes(9))
```

but when i input (9) i got [2,3] not a [2,3,5,7]
what is a problem?

Comment: There's no need to use `elif` when the condition is the exact opposite of the first condition. Use `else:`

Comment: Why is the function called `factorialofprimes`? It doesn't calculate factorials.

Comment: Because my last goal is multiply all element in list like 2*3*5*7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current `factorialofprimes` function, you call `break` when you encounter a non-prime. `break` is used to exit the `for` loop completely, whereas you would rather `continue` the loop.

Alternatively, you could `append(i)` if `i` is prime, and do nothing if otherwise. This is demonstrated below:

```
from primenumber import isPrimeNumber
def factorialofprimes(n):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if isPrimeNumber(i):
            primes.append(i)
    return primes

print(factorialofprimes(9))
```

Comment: I appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> but when i input (9) i got [2,3] not a [2,3,5,7] what is a problem?

You break out of the loop at i=4 as it's not a prime number.

Comment: I think you mean `i = 4`